# Access route / directory with variable without preventing other routing

Tags: php, symfony

I am developping my site as route .

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="index"))
 */
```

However for now
it turns out that "/" must have to get parameters `mode`.

So I want to access index, with two mode(GO,WALK) and default(GO).

So I made like this,

```
/**
 * @Route("/{mode}", name="index",defaults={"mode": "go"}))
 */
```

Now it works like this,

`/ -> goes GO mode`

`/go -> goes GO mode`

`/walk -> goes WALK mode`

At first, I thought it is perfect!

However I have problem now.

I can't access other bundle like `/admin/dashboard`

Normaly in this case, I think i should use like `/?mode=go`

However on Symfony framework there is no samles to use `?`.

What is the best practice for this case??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to control the order of the routes and put the wildcard one at the end. You can do this in the routes.yml file. Make sure if you put any routes in this file make sure it is at the end of this file

```
index:
    resource: "\App\Controller\IndexController"
    type: annotation
```

Comment: Thank you I change the order of Routings, then it works!!